# Issue with intregration question

Tags: integration

> $$
> \int_0^1 \frac{5x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx
> $$

Hi having an issue with the question above.

So far, I have

$ u = x^2 + 1$

$ \frac {du}{dx} = 2x $

$ 2xdu = dx$

$\int_2^1 \frac {5x}{\sqrt(x^2 + 1)} 2xdu $

Stuck after this. Cant seem to factorise?

Any help would be appreciated

$\frac 52 \int_1^2 \frac {du}{\sqrt(u)} $

$\frac 52 \int_1^2 u^\frac{-1}{2} $

$\frac 52 \int_1^2 2u^\frac12 $

$\frac 52 (2^2 + 1) - (1^1 + 1) $

$\frac 52 (5 - 2) = 7\frac12 $

Is this right?

Comment: You say $\frac{du}{dx}=2x,$ which implies that $\frac{du}{2x}= dx,$ when changing the differentials.  The error you made is you incorrectly "solved for" $dx.$

Comment: Made an attempt at answering. Any input is welcomed

Answer (score 4):

If $u = x^2 + 1$ then $du = 2xdx$ and so you get
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{5x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx
 = \frac{5}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{2xdx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}
 = \frac{5}{2} \int_1^2 \frac{du}{\sqrt{u}}
$$

Can you take it from here?

**UPDATE**

Following your updated question, here is the rest of the solution
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^1 \frac{5x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx
 &= \frac{5}{2} \int_1^2 \frac{du}{\sqrt{u}}
  = \frac{5}{2} \int_1^2 u^{-1/2}du\\
 &= \frac{5}{2} \left. 2u^{1/2}\right|_1^2 \\
 &= \frac{5}{2} \times 2 \times \left(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1} \right) \\
 &= 5 \left(\sqrt{2}-1 \right)
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes completely see where that came from.  Also now notice where my mistake was made.  Would I go on and divide du by u? to get d^-1/2 ? Apoligies cant seem to use mathjax syntax while commenting

Comment: Made an attempt at answering the question in the original post. Am I right?  @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner

Comment: @JohnAllen a couple mistakes in your update, see my update for full answer and compare

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes I can see my issues!

Answer (score 0):

HINT: write your integral in the form $$\frac{5}{2}\int \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$$ and set $$t=x^2+1$$

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is on this step:
$$\frac{du}{dx}=2x \not \Rightarrow 2x~du=dx$$
However, it should be:
$$\frac{1}{2x}~du=dx$$
Then, the $x$ terms should cancel out.

---

Also, you've made a mistake in the order of the integration limits. Note that:
$$u=0^2+1=1 \qquad \text{where}~~ x=0$$
And:
$$u=1^2+1=2 \qquad \text{where}~~ x=1$$
Therefore, your integration limits should be from $1$ to $2$ **in that order**.

---

Combining this, you should obtain:
$$\int_1^2 \frac{5}{2\sqrt{u}}~du$$
Can you continue?

Comment: I have attempted to answer the question in the original post following on from your hint.

Comment: @JohnAllen You've made a mistake. If you evaluate the integral, you should obtain:
$$\frac{5}{2} \int_1^2 u^{-1/2}~du=\frac{5}{2} \left[2\sqrt{u}\right]_1^2=5\left[\sqrt{u}\right]_1^2$$
Then, this gives:
$$5(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1})=5(\sqrt{2}-1)$$
See your mistake now? [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+0+to+1+5x%2F(sqrt(x%5E2%2B1))) agrees.

Comment: Yes, The mistake is actually shocking. Managed to forget about a 2 and a sqrt ! Impressively stupid ha  Thanks for the help. For the definate integral do I then sub the values for x, 2 and 1 into the above equation?

Comment: @JohnAllen Not sure exactly what you mean. This is the solution to the original definite integral because we **already changed the bounds** from $x\in [0,1]$ to $u\in [1,2]$.

Comment: Is the final answer $$ 5(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1}) = 2.07 $$ ?

Comment: @JohnAllen Yes. However, since $2.07$ is an approximate answer, you should be using: $\approx$.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.